# Read/Write ICC Profile In Images with Go and OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, go, color-profile

I'm writing code to resize images with Go and the [go-opencv package](https://github.com/lazywei/go-opencv). After the resize happens, the image that I write out is missing the ICC profile from the original image.

Are there any Go or C libraries that can read/write ICC profiles? The goal is to not use command line tools but Go/C libraries so I can do all of this within the process. I know exiftool exists and can do this for me, but I'd rather not shell out to a perl script.

Comment: opencv discards any image headers while reading, so no icc or exif data preserved. (also, wrapping opencv's deprecated c-api to go is a terrible idea, imho. totally outdated stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, I've found [libvips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS) and the go [bindings](https://github.com/DAddYE/vips).

libvips doesn't strip any embedded profiles. This [blog post](http://libvips.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-libvips-handles-colour.html) mentions this:

> The file load/save operations (like tiffload, jpegsave etc.) don't do anything with colour. On load they attach any ICC profiles they see to the vips image as metadata and on save they write any attached profile to the file. They aim to give you something very close to what's actually stored in the file and leave colour processing for you to arrange.

Answer (score 2):

I only know of [go-iccjpeg](https://github.com/vimeo/go-iccjpeg):

> A small utility package to extract **[International Color Consortium (ICC) profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile)** from JPEG buffers.

```
import "github.com/vimeo/go-iccjpeg/iccjpeg"

iccjpeg.GetICCBuf(input io.Reader) ([]byte, error)
```

> It takes an `io.Reader` with a JPEG, and returns a buffer with the embedded ICC profile from that JPEG, if there is one.
>   If there is not one, it returns an empty buffer.